# Why is my regression insignificant when I merge data that produced two significant regressions?

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, regression-coefficients

Sorry for the confusing title, I think this is a general statistics question, but I'm working in R. I have a combined dataset of two samples from different countries (n=240 and n=1,010), and when I run a linear regression between the same three variables in each dataset, both datasets produce a significant result, with almost identical coefficients. However, when I merge the datasets and run the same regression on the combined dataset, it is no longer significant. Can anyone explain this?

In case it matters, the regression has the form `lm(a~b*c)`.

Comment: If the two regressions have significant but different slopes (very different and possibly of different sign) there is no reason to think that combining the data into a single regression will give a significant slope.

Comment: Like I said, the coefficients are almost the same. Thank you for your comment though, and I'm curious to hear if you have any advice on how to proceed in trying to solve this problem!

Comment: Sorry, I missed the part where you said that you had almost identical coefficients.  But what exactly did you mean by almost identical?  What were the significant levels for each?

Comment: Also what was the significance level for the combined regression?

Comment: The big dataset was (b= -0.28, p<0.001). The smaller one was (b=-0.35, p=0.002). And when I add in covariates the distance between coefficients gets even smaller. The combined regression was (b=-0.002, p=0.954).

Comment: What about the intercepts?

Comment: Including the intercepts, the big dataset was (int= -26.13, b= -0.28, p<0.001). The smaller one was (int=-26.06, b=-0.35, p=0.002). The combined regression was (int=-9.01, b=-0.002, p=0.954)

Comment: Add the dataset as a confounding variable. Performing a regression of the form `lm(a~b * c * dataset)` will make the Simpson's Paradox obvious here,

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Without seeing your data, this is difficult to answer definitively.  One possibility is that your datasets span different ranges of the independent variable. It is well-known that combining data across different groups can sometimes reverse correlations seen in each group individually.  This effect is known as [Simpson's Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox).

Comment: Wow, that's really interesting, I had never heard of Simpson's Paradox! I wonder if you could give me some advice about how to proceed in trying to answer my research question, which is to see whether variable c moderates variable b 's effect on variable a. I'm puzzled as to how I should address something like this, because it seems like whether I say c moderates b, I'm correct in each country individually, but incorrect in general! I guess that's the paradox, but I'm still stumped.

Comment: Assuming you are dealing with Simpson's paradox here (something that we haven't fully established!), I think there are two key questions.  First, do your two datasets correspond to different levels of a **meaningful** grouping factor. Second, if so, does the variation introduced by this factor represent nuisance variation that you want to control for (as opposed to interesting variation that you want to study).  If you answered yes to both questions, then you might consider estimating a fixed effect of group (continued)

Comment: (continued) which might allow the model to draw parallel lines (with the slope of interest) through each of your two groups, while dealing with the between-group variation by giving the two lines different intercepts.  But I emphasize that these are decisions that can only be made with a full conceptual/theoretical understanding of the problem that your analysis is supposed to answer.

Comment: +1 @Benji - Imagine two x-y scatter plots of data pts with the same slope, but one scatter plot is shifted to the right of the other on the x-axis, such that the best fitting regression line for both scatter plots is essentially flat.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Jacob. I don't know anything about fixed effects at this point, but I'll look into it. @RobertF, I don't think that's the issue, the means and ranges of all variables involved are very similar in both datasets. I think I actually figured it out by graphing out the interaction - there appears to be a quadratic relationship between one of the independent variables and the dependent variable, but only in one of the countries. As a result, the slopes of the *lower half of values* of variable b cancel each other out when the two models are put together. Seem plausible?

Comment: @BenjiKaveladze Yes (see my answer below), but you'll want to verify this is the case by, for example, removing the country with the quadratic relationship from the dataset and see if the observed regression coefficients still change. At any rate, this illustrates how linear regressions can fail to detect nonlinear relationships which other techniques (like boosted regression, neural networks, decision trees, etc.) can model more effectively.

Comment: @BenjiKaveladze : "whether variable c moderates variable b 's effect on variable a"...  Do you want to show that c has the *same* moderation effect on b in every country or do you want to show (the much weaker) c has some moderation effect on b in every country or do you want to show (the even weaker) c has some moderation effect in some country.  You seem to have expected the first, but gotten the Null outcome for the second.

Comment: I just want to know in general if the interaction of b*c predicts a. Substituting the actual variables, it would be "do stressors moderate the link between social support and depression " (depression being the dependent variable).

Answer (score 17):

If your data looks something like this then the reason may be more obvious.  Your two original regression lines would be almost parallel and look reasonably plausible but combined they produce a different result which is probably not very helpful.

[image: regrssion]

The data for this chart came from using the R code

```
exdf <- data.frame(
  x=c(-64:-59, -52:-47),
  y=c(-8.29, -8.36, -9.05, -9.30, -9.20, -9.69, 
      -7.90, -8.34, -8.49, -8.85, -9.38, -9.65),
  col=c(rep("blue",6), rep("red",6)) )
fitblue  <- lm(y ~ x, data=exdf[exdf$col=="blue",])
fitred   <- lm(y ~ x, data=exdf[exdf$col=="red" ,])
fitcombo <- lm(y ~ x, data=exdf)
plot(y ~ x, data=exdf, col=col)
abline(fitblue , col="blue")
abline(fitred  , col="red" )
abline(fitcombo, col="black")
```

which reports

```
> summary(fitblue)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x, data = exdf[exdf$col == "blue", ])

Residuals:
       1        2        3        4        5        6 
-0.00619  0.20295 -0.20790 -0.17876  0.20038 -0.01048 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -26.14895    2.91063  -8.984  0.00085 ***
x            -0.27914    0.04731  -5.900  0.00413 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.1979 on 4 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8969,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8712 
F-statistic: 34.81 on 1 and 4 DF,  p-value: 0.004128

> summary(fitred)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x, data = exdf[exdf$col == "red", ])

Residuals:
        7         8         9        10        11        12 
-0.005238 -0.095810  0.103619  0.093048 -0.087524 -0.008095 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -26.06505    1.12832  -23.10 2.08e-05 ***
x            -0.34943    0.02278  -15.34 0.000105 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.0953 on 4 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9833,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9791 
F-statistic: 235.3 on 1 and 4 DF,  p-value: 0.0001054

> summary(fitcombo)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x, data = exdf)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-0.8399 -0.4548 -0.0750  0.4774  0.9999 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -9.269561   1.594455  -5.814  0.00017 ***
x           -0.007109   0.028549  -0.249  0.80839    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.617 on 10 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.006163,  Adjusted R-squared:  -0.09322 
F-statistic: 0.06201 on 1 and 10 DF,  p-value: 0.8084
```

not too far away from your statistics and with further work could be made closer

Comment: +1 for the good simulation of the Simpson's paradox. Another example in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/185047/is-this-simpsons-paradox-on-the-titanic-data-set .

Answer (score 4):

It's also possible the data points in each dataset may have completely different distributions due to outliers and/or nonlinear relationships between $x$ and $y$, and yet still share nearly identical linear regression coefficients, standard errors, and statistically significant $p$-values. Combining the two datasets could create a dataset that no longer has a strong linear relationship. See [Anscombe's Quartet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anscombe%27s_quartet). A visual representation of numerous datasets sharing the same summary statistics but radically different scatterplots can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DbJyPELmhJc). My recommendation would be to closely examine the scatterplots of both datasets.

Comment: In addition to examine the scatterplots, I would try to repeat regression using the country as an additional variable (a~b*c*country). This way you will see if some coefficients change significantly between countries.

Comment: @Pere When I include country in the model (a~b*c*country), the result produced is that the b*c interaction variable becomes significantly related to a (b=-0.35, p<0.001). Can I interpret that as evidence that b*c predicts a? It just seems weird to me that b*c only predicts a when I introduce the country variable into the equation. Thanks!

Comment: @BenjiKaveladze I'm not sure to understand your comment. I suggest posting the whole summary, maybe in another question. However, significant bc interactions means that you can take in account bc to get better predictions of a, which is equivalent to say that for different values of c you get a diferent relation between a and b.

Comment: @Pere Maybe it will help if I write the actual question, which is "do stressors moderate the link between social support and depression"? So the model is (depression~support*stress). My question is whether I should instead use the model (depression~support*stress*country). This is tricky for me because only when I use the second model does the support*stress interaction become significant. When country is not in the model, the support*stress interaction is not significant. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

For more on Simpson's Paradox see Pearl, J., & Mackenzie, D. (2018). Paradoxes Galore! The Book of Why: The New Science of Cause and Effect (Kindle ed., pp. 2843-3283). New York: Basic Books. Also, see Pearl's Causality.

In his book, Pearl gives an example very similar to yours.  The problem is that there is a confounding variable that is affecting both the independent variable(s) and the dependent variable.  In Pearl's example, the question is, Why is an anti-heart attack drug bad for women, bad for men, but good for people? (when the two gender samples are combined).  The answer is that gender is a confounding variable that impacts who takes the drug (women are far more likely), and also the prevalence of heart attack (men are far more likely).  The solution to confounding variables is to condition on them.  The can be done in two ways: (1) Using regression analysis, make gender a variable; (2) Analyze the average effect of the drug for the two genders separately; then compute the weighted average (weighted by percent in population of the genders, here 1/2) of the effects.

Pearl would say that you have to have a model of the phenomenon you are studying, i.e., an exhaustive theory that takes into account all the variables involved in the response.  Developing such a model and theory can take months of reading to understand the work of others in the field.  However, recall that one left out variable can bias the results and make them meaningless or just plain wrong.

Pearl would also write that you cannot extract causality from data; for that you need a theoretical model.  However, once you have a theory and a model, you can use data to support them.